# JBoss server connection refused on localhost:1099

Tags: java, jboss, jboss5.x

I have an instance of JBoss 5.0.1 GA running on a remote server. The server attempts to start a batch service located on the same instance, but it reports connection refused. I found some webpage that said to add the localhost address to jndi.properties, but then the server fails to start altogether. The error code:

```
10:27:23,831 DEBUG [TimedSocketFactory] createSocket, hostAddr: localhost/127.0.0.1, port: 1099, localAddr: null, localPort: 0, timeout: 0
10:27:23,831 DEBUG [NamingContext] Failed to connect to localhost:1099
javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to server localhost/127.0.0.1:1099 [Root exception is javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException:
Failed to connect to server localhost/127.0.0.1:1099 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]]
```

I run the command

```
netstat -anpt
```

and the list contains the IP of this server and port 1099.

I run

```
telnet [IP of server] 8080
```

and it connects successfully.

I run

```
telnet [IP of server] 1099
```

and it returns connection refused and some weird characters.

Any ideas on what to do about this? Thanks

Comment: What is `batch service`? What it do? What port it used?

Comment: Is it the correct port? Check with jboss-service.xm

Comment: it retrieves some data from an external service and adds it to our database. The connectivity works between the external service and our database, as the application can successfully access them in other cases. Well, port 1099 seems to be used.

Comment: 1099 is usuall uses for RMI. Try to do `netstat -anpt` (on linux) and see what port is listened. If 1099 not listened, you cannot connect to it. If some service listened on this port, try `telnet localhost 1099`.

Comment: In general, first thing to do - check that your service on port 1099 is up and running.

Comment: The port 1099 is listed with the netstat command, for the server IP address but not for localhost. Does it matter?

Comment: So log in to your remote server and try `telnet localhost 1099`. `$ telnet localhost 5432
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'` If you will se something like this, conection is OK, and ploblem need further investigations.

Comment: @user1340582 And edit your question and add all usefull information you obtain, maybe someone will help.

Comment: I edited my original question. telnet of server IP with port 8080 succeeds, but fails for port 1099

Comment: There is a distant possibility that your server (os) is blocking communication to port 1099, more so if it is a linux machine like CentOS or RHEL. This is a possibility, so let us know if this is the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Log in into server via ssh and do next actions from terminal on this server.
2. Run `netstat -anpt | grep 1099`
3. Check state of 1099 port is LISTEN. Remember program name and pid ( last column output of netstat, should be something like `5812/java`)
4. Try investigate, what program used it. Run `ps aux | grep xxxx` where xxxx - pid from step 3
5. Check program arguments and be sure it is Jboss instance.
6. Check `iptables` settings, be sure incoming connection to 1099 is allowed from localhost ( it should be by default)
7. try connect to port 1099
8. Temporally disable iptables, if it possible.
9. try connect to port 1099
10. Check proxy settings, maybe you go to localhost through proxy.

Answer (score 0):

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/SOA-1534 seems to be the root cause. If you don't want the naming provider url to be configured, then just pass the following VM arg to override the value.`-Djava.naming.provider.url=` for run.sh of your jboss.