# JBoss Server stopping error

Tags: jboss

I am using JBoss Server in my project.

The JBoss version is 4.2.3

When I am stopping the server, at that time the server is giving error and is not getting stopped.

The console is showing the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.CommunicationException: Could not obtain connection to any of these urls: localhost:1099 [Root exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to server localhost:1099 [Root exception is javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server localhost:1099 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]]]

at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.checkRef(NamingContext.java:1562)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:634)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:627)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
at org.jboss.Shutdown.main(Shutdown.java:214)
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to server localhost:1099 [Root exception is javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server localhost:1099 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]]
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:274)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.checkRef(NamingContext.java:1533)
... Caused by: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server localhost:1099 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:248)
... Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:328)
at org.jnp.interfaces.TimedSocketFactory.createSocket(TimedSocketFactory.java:84)
at org.jnp.interfaces.TimedSocketFactory.createSocket(TimedSocketFactory.java:77)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:244)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jboss-server-connection-refused-on-localhost1099](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526110/jboss-server-connection-refused-on-localhost1099).

Comment: No it is not the duplicate. Please check the question and then provide link.

Comment: Have you looked at this [JBoss community discussion thread](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/202628)?

Comment: The link you suggested does not yield fruitful solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is old but I've faced the same error and I've found the solution.

I edited the **jboss-service.xml** file that is located at the following path:

> <_jboss_installation_folder_>/server/<_instance_name>_/conf

You have to find the NamingService mbean:

```
<mbean code="org.jboss.naming.NamingService" name="jboss:service=Naming" xmbean-dd="resource:xmdesc/NamingService-xmbean.xml">
```

and change the port attribute to 1099, eg:

```
<attribute name="Port">1099</attribute>
```