# This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect. deployed using jboss 7.1

Tags: browser, jboss, jboss7.x

I deployed my project using jboss7.1 and also it deployed successfully
but I can't access though browser it says This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect. how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526110/jboss-server-connection-refused-on-localhost1099) mentions,

> 

```
1 Log in into server via ssh and do next actions from terminal on this server.
2. Run netstat on the port
3.Check state of 1099 port is LISTEN. Remember program name and pid ( last column output of netstat, should be something like 5812/java)
4. Try investigate, what program used it. Run ps aux | grep xxxx where xxxx - pid from step 3
```